# ListView binds to a collection, how to access an event in a parent class?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-runtime

In my WinRT project I have a ListView as follows;

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Survey.SelectedSection.QuestionsAndNavigation, Mode=TwoWay}"
    IsSwipeEnabled="False"
    SelectionMode="None"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    Background="White"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ResourceKey=QuestionDisplay}"
    ItemContainerStyle=
        "{StaticResource ResourceKey=QuestionListViewItemContainerStyle}">
</ListView>
```

Note the line;
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Survey.SelectedSection.QuestionsAndNavigation}"
The collection QuestionsAndNavigation ends with some navigation buttons with this in the UserControl;

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Button Margin="0,40,40,0"
        IsEnabled="{Binding Path=PreviousSectionId, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=IntBooleanConverter}}"
        Command="{Binding Path=NavigateToPreviousSectionCommand}">&lt;&lt; Save and Previous Section</Button>
    <Button Margin="0,40,0,0"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=NextSectionId, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=IntBooleanConverter}}"
            Command="{Binding Path=NavigateToNextSectionCommand}">Save and Next Section &gt;&gt;</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

and displays as follows;
[image]

Now the problem is that in the bind path: Survey.SelectedSection.QuestionsAndNavigation I want the command to be located in the great GrandParent class SurveyPageViewModel (which contains the Survey object) rather than in the embedded collection class QuestionsAndNavigation. By default the Data Context looks in the wrong class.
Important to recognise that this is not inheritance. The "Survey" here maps to the SurveyPageViewModel class which contains a Survey that maps to a SurveyViewModel class, a SelectedSection which maps onto a SectionViewModel class and that contains QuestionsAndNavigation which is a collection of QuestionViewModel classes.

So the code in the QuestionViewModel:

```
private void NavigateToNextSection()
{
    NavigateToSection(this.NextSectionId);
}

private void NavigateToPreviousSection()
{
    NavigateToSection(this.PreviousSectionId);
}

private void NavigateToSection(int sectionId)
{
    NavService.Navigate("NewSection", sectionId);
}
```

does not go to the SurveyPageViewModel and I cannot set up NavService in the QuestionViewModel class as it is not there, it is a property in the SurveyPageViewModel instead.

EDIT.
So thanks to the answer by Eric, my ListView contains a x:Name = "ListResponses". I use this in the Path of my Buttons:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Button Margin="0,40,40,0"
        IsEnabled="{Binding Path=PreviousSectionId, 
            Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=IntBooleanConverter}}"
        Command="{Binding 
            Path=DataContext.SaveThenPreviousSectionCommand,
            ElementName=ListResponses}">&lt;&lt; Previous Section</Button>
    <Button Margin="0,40,0,0"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=NextSectionId, 
                Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=IntBooleanConverter}}"
            Command="{Binding  
                Path=DataContext.SaveThenNextSectionCommand,
                ElementName=ListResponses}">Next Section &gt;&gt;</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

And I have put the event hookups in the SurveyPageViewModel, but they are not wired up for some reason that I would like to know the answer to;

```
public ICommand SaveThenPreviousSectionCommand { get; private set; }
public ICommand SaveThenNextSectionCommand { get; private set; }
```

...
(in the constructor)

```
SaveThenPreviousSectionCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoSaveThenPreviousSection);
        SaveThenNextSectionCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoSaveThenNextSection);
```

...

```
   private async void DoSaveThenPreviousSection()
    {
        var i = 1;
    }

    private async void DoSaveThenNextSection()
    {
        var i = 0;
    }
```

EDIT: This is the full XAML file for the page

```
<prism:VisualStateAwarePage x:Class="M.Survey.Views.SurveyPage"

                            x:Name="pageRoot"
                            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                            xmlns:views="using:M.Survey.Views"
                            xmlns:local="using:M.Survey"
                            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                            xmlns:prism="using:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps"
                            xmlns:mvvm="using:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm"
                            mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="true"
                            xmlns:userControls="using:M.Survey.UserControls"
                            mc:Ignorable="d"
                            xmlns:converters="using:M.Survey.Converters"
                            Loaded="pageRoot_Loaded"
                            Unloaded="pageRoot_Unloaded"
                            xmlns:templateSelectors="using:M.Survey.TemplateSelectors">

    <prism:VisualStateAwarePage.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/AllQuestionDataTemplates.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Styles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/DataTemplates.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <templateSelectors:QuestionTemplateSelector x:Key="QuestionDisplay"
                TextEntry="{StaticResource TextEntry}"
                DateTimeEntry="{StaticResource DateTimeEntry}"
                BoolEntry="{StaticResource BoolEntry}"
                IntEntry="{StaticResource IntEntry}"
                SelectEntry="{StaticResource SelectEntry}"
                DecimalEntry="{StaticResource DecimalEntry}"
                LargeTextArea="{StaticResource LargeTextArea}"
                SorEntry="{StaticResource SorEntry}"
                Additional="{StaticResource AdditionalEntry}"
                Miscellaneous="{StaticResource Miscellaneous}"
                Dim="{StaticResource Dim}"
                Signature="{StaticResource Signature}"
                SectionNavigation="{StaticResource SectionNavigation}"/>

            <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
            <converters:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter" />

        </ResourceDictionary>

    </prism:VisualStateAwarePage.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AppBackgroundColor}" />
        </Grid.Background>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MulalleyBlueBrush}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20, 0, 0, 5">
                    <Button Margin="0, 0, 15, 0" Command="{Binding Path=TryGoHomeCommand}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MediumHeaderTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=Job.ShortDisplayAddress}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

                    <StackPanel Margin="40, 0, 0, 6" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30">
                        <ProgressRing Height="30" Width="30" Foreground="White" IsActive="{Binding Path=WorkInProgress}" Visibility="{Binding Path=WorkInProgress, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10, 0, 0, 10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="{Binding Path=FeedbackMsg}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SmallHeaderTextBlockStyle}" />

                </StackPanel>

                <Grid Margin="0, 0, 15, 5" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="Internet" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MediumHeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="10, 0, 15, 6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=ConnectionStatus}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SmallHeaderStyle}" />

                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="Server" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MediumHeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="2" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="10, 0, 15, 6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Path=VpnStatus}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SmallHeaderStyle}" />

                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="User" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MediumHeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="4" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="10, 0, 0, 6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding Path=User.DisplayName}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SmallHeaderStyle}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <TextBlock Width="80" Margin="100, 0, 30, 0" Text="{Binding Path=AnswersCompleteDisplay}" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MediumHeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>

                    <Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SaveButtonStyle}" Content="Save" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}"  />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MulalleyBlue}" Opacity=".2" />
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ListView
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Survey.Sections, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Survey.SelectedSection, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ListViewItemContainerStyle}"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SurveySectionDataTemplate}"
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                            />
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="30, 30, 15, 20">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="*" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" = Required " FontSize="20"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ListView 
                            x:Name="ListResponses"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Survey.SelectedSection.QuestionsAndNavigation, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                            SelectionMode="None"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                            Background="White"
                            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ResourceKey=QuestionDisplay}"
                            ItemContainerStyle=
                                "{StaticResource ResourceKey=QuestionListViewItemContainerStyle}">
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <userControls:SurveyDialogUserControl />
        <userControls:SurveyReassignedDialogUserControl />
        <userControls:CopyFromUserControl />

    </Grid>

    <prism:VisualStateAwarePage.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar Name="commandBar">
            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Label="Settings" Icon="Setting" Click="AppBarButton_Click" />
                <AppBarButton Label="Log" Icon="Admin" Click="LogButton_Click" />
                <AppBarButton Label="Refresh" Icon="Refresh" Command="{Binding Path=RefershAllDataCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=WorkInProgress, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=InverseBooleanConverter}}" Visibility="{Binding Path=VpnOnline, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                <AppBarButton Label="Copy From" Icon="Copy" Click="CopyButton_Click" Command="{Binding Path=ShowCopyFromCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=WorkInProgress, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=InverseBooleanConverter}}" />
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </prism:VisualStateAwarePage.BottomAppBar>


</prism:VisualStateAwarePage>
```

And this is the User control XAML;

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="M.Survey.UserControls.SectionNavigation"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:M.Survey.UserControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:converters="using:M.Survey.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="30"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:IntBooleanConverter x:Key="IntBooleanConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Button Margin="0,40,40,0"
                IsEnabled="{Binding Path=PreviousSectionId, 
                    Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=IntBooleanConverter}}"
                Command="{Binding 
                    Path=DataContext.SaveThenPreviousSectionCommand,
                    ElementName=ListResponses}">&lt;&lt; Previous Section</Button>
            <Button Margin="0,40,0,0"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=NextSectionId, 
                        Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=IntBooleanConverter}}"
                    Command="{Binding  
                        Path=DataContext.SaveThenNextSectionCommand,
                        ElementName=ListResponses}">Next Section &gt;&gt;</Button>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was helped a lot towards getting the answer from Eric, the guy who gives the other answer.
In order to get communication between 2 classes that are embedded in their own complicated designs, one way to do this is to use the EventAggregator pattern. As it happens the app I am working on uses Prism which as it's own implementation of EventAggregator. This pattern enables you to publish a payload which is picked up by subscribe events on the receiving class.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the ListView XAML is in the same file as the Button XAML (and the ListView is x:Name="listView"):

```
<Button Margin="0,40,0,0"
        IsEnabled="{Binding Path=NextSectionId, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=IntBooleanConverter}}"
        Command="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=DataContext.Survey.DESIRED_COMMAND}">Save and Next Section &gt;&gt;</Button>
```

Additionally, you could also pass an instance of the Survey viewmodel into the question viewmodel, upon instantiation (depends on how you are creating your viewmodels).

Finally, you could also use an event publishing system (e.g. MVVM Light Messenger) to publish an event when the button is clicked that the Survey is wired to respond to.

Comment: I am sure your answer is right but I can't get it to wire up. When I click on the button nothing happens. Incidentally I was wrong about the ViewModel tree. SurveyPageViewModel contains 1 SurveyViewModel which contains 1 SelectedSection which contains a collection of QuestionViewModel objects. The command events are on the SurveyPageViewModel class. So what makes sense to me is that in identifying the name of the ListView then in the button "Path=DataContext.DESIRED_COMMAND". The Button is in a UserControl file and NOT in the same file as the LIstView. Is that the problem?

Comment: Incidentally passing a reference of the SurveyPageViewModel to the QuestionViewModel would create a circular reference so I do not think that would work. And I am not familiar with MVVM Light Messenger. I looked it up but it looks complicated to me (I am new to XAML)

Comment: I have updated my answer so you can see what I have done.

Comment: Can you post the full XAML file, so I can see which items are in each others scopes?

Comment: Just posted it at the end of the question

Comment: OK. I had thought that the ListView and buttons were in the same scope (or at least file). XAML ElementName bindings won't work. My best recommendation would be to use a pub sub like the MVVM Light Messenger class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx).

Comment: My application uses Prism so I used the pub sub functionality from that and ... it works!